# Does the aws-sdk 1.8.3 gem support AWS Elastic Transcoder

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-elastic-transcoder

Does the aws-sdk `1.8.3` gem support AWS Elastic Transcoder API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWS SDK for Ruby added support for Amazon Elastic Transcoder in the 1.8.1 version of the gem.  See [the release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Ruby/6228115877364431) and the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/ElasticTranscoder/Client.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be added as a placeholder [25 days ago](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/lib/aws/elastic_transcoder). Currently nothing seems to be supported, but it looks like they intend to.

I would check the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/) or github periodically. I imagine they'll have it in soon.

Comment: Is it true that it still lacks support, the previous comment mentions its already supported.